# my gradle does not work properly

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I move .gradle folder from my home (ubuntu) to another drive. then change the location of gradle from android studio(v 1.3) setting. after this my gradle does not work anymore and I get this error:

Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not download android-ui.aar (com.github.markushi:android-ui:1.2)
>   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/markushi/android-ui/1.2/android-ui-1.2.aar'.
>   Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/markushi/android-ui/1.2/android-ui-1.2.aar'.
>   Connection to https://jcenter.bintray.com refused

then I move .gradle folder to first place and reset gradle location in android studio settings. but still i get above error!

this is my settings

[image]

beside this my gradle sync takes too long time. 30 min and then as I said finished with above error.

sometimes this problem occurred because of proxy but my proxy setting is here:
[image]

I always open android studio with terminal and this command: ./studio.sh
as I know terminal proxy has no effect on gradle proxy and it always works fine.

Comment: Are you sur you have no proxy on your network ? Looks like android studio cannot access to internet

Comment: @marshallino16 as you see the settings I do not set any proxy but if there is another way to set a proxy let me know

Comment: The question is, do you have a proxy on your network ?

Comment: @marshallino16 I use Ubuntu 14.04 sometimes I use proxy from settings>>network.  sometimes set it to none and click on "apply system wide". in both situation my gradle does not work yesterday. after this problems I reinstall android studio and gradle right now and then it works with proxy but it still not working without it! maybe gradle has been blocked for Iranian developers!